# ¿Como resetear un input tipo file y resetear el valor del campo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente tengo el siguiente formulario donde si cargo el archivo en alguno de los campos me devuleve un valor en el campo IDE y se habilita el boton de enviar, pero al momento de quitar el archivo el campo IDE se queda con el valor como lo muestro a continuacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo quito el archivo mi valor de IDE se queda , almenos que refresque la pagina se queda vacio y nuevamente asigna el valor dependiento cual este lleno, EL OBJETIVO ES RESETEAR LOS INPUTS FILE Y QUE ME RESETEE EL VALOR DEL CAMPO AL MOMENTO QUE ELIMINENE EL ARCHVO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 $(function() {
  var file1 = false;
  var file2 = false;
 
  
 // const dato=document.getElementById("dato");
  
  let habilitado=1;
  let habilitado2=2;
  let habilitado3=3;
  let deshabilitado=0;



  $('#Field1').change(function() {
    // si esto cumple, "file1" es true, de lo contrario es false.
    file1 = this.files.length > 0;
    verificarInputs();
     
  });

  $('#Field62').change(function() {
    // si esto cumple, "file2" es true, de lo contrario es false.
    file2 = this.files.length > 0;
    verificarInputs();
   
  });

  function verificarInputs() {
    // Si "file1" y "file2" son true, habilito el botón, de lo contrario permanece deshabilitado.
    if (file1 && file2) {
     
      $('.Submit').prop('disabled', false);// ESTA HABILITADO
     document.getElementById("Field66").value = habilitado2
 
    
    } else if(!file1 || file2){
     
   $('.Submit').prop('disabled', false);// ESTA HABILITADO
     document.getElementById("Field66").value = habilitado3
     
    }else if(!file2 || file1){
    
     $('.Submit').prop('disabled', false);// ESTA HABILITADO
      document.getElementById("Field66").value = habilitado

    
    }else{
    
    
     $('.Submit').prop('disabled', true);// ESTA DESHABILITADO
         document.getElementById("Field66").value = deshabilitado
    
    }
  }
});
```

Asi tengo mi codigo

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo completar un [mcve]. Es importante que sea _completo_ (HTML, javascript) y sería ideal que sea _mínimo_ (que no tenga otras cosas que no son relevantes para entender/reproducir el problema que tienes. Un saludo.